# Prefixing routes in YML - only one controller

Tags: symfony, routes, prefix

I have a question about routes in symfony2:

When I want to add a prefix to controller by annotation, I do it like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class BlogController extends Controller
{}
```

and it works fine. But how can I do the same thing using only YML?

I know that's i can add it to routing.yml:

```
mybundle_blog:
    resource: "@MybundleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /blog
```

but then the path "/blog" applies to all controllers in **MybundleBundle**. I want to make it work just for the controller **BlogController**

Help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
mybundle_blog:
    resource: "@MyBundleBundle/Controller/BlogController/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /blog
```

Comment: I tried to do it earlier, but I received a message "Cannot load resource "@MyBundleBundle/Controller/BlogController/". Make sure the "MyBundleBundle/Controller/BlogController/" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@MyBundleBundle/Controller/BlogController/" is not empty."

Of course the class "BlogController" exists in the correct directory, and when i use an annotations then everything works fine.